# ERROR: undefined method `comemnts' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, blogs

I follow guide.ruby.org , but some error I don't know how to solve it.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list

  def index
    @comments = @list.comments.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def create
    @comment = @list.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to list_path(@list)  }
            format.js
        end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Check the comment form, something went wrong.'
      render root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end

end
```

`

```
# gem 'simple_form'
# gem 'foundation-rails'
    <div class="comment-form">
        <%= simple_form_for [@list, @list.comemnts.build] do |f| %>
            <%= f.textarea :content, placeholder: 'add comment...',
                               class: "comment_content",
                               id: "comment_content_#{list.id}",
                               data: { list_id: "#{list.id}",
                               value: "#{list.comments.count}" } %>

           <%=f.button :submit, 'New Comment', class: 'comment-submit-button' %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
```

But I got error, when I step-to-step from guide, all is OK,here is the bug info:

> undefined method `comemnts' for #

something wrong? Thanks answer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a simple spelling mistake as I can see.

```
@list.comemnts.build
```

should be

```
@list.comments.build
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the view - should be

```
@list.comments.build
```

not

```
@list.comemnts.build
```